# Trouble accessing and printing the parameters from a Bus in a MATLAB Script

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, bus

I am trying to write a list of all the names of a bus I'm using as argument for a MATLAB Function.

Right now I'm using:

```
function write_list(busObject)

fileID = fopen('list.m', 'w');

fprintf(fileID, busObject.Elements.Name);

fclose(fileID);
```

The Output is just the first element of the bus. There are a lot of elements.
Can someone please enlighten me?

I was expecting the output I get when calling busObject.Elements.Name in a command Windows with all of the names. Right now I only get the first one.

Comment: What do you see when you try the command "busObject.Elements.Name"?

Comment: Only the First Name of the Element of the bus. (There are 60 Elements from different datatypes)

Comment: you should see many answers, which you can put together in 1 variable using curly braces (a cell array). see `doc cell`;  `{busObject.Elements.Name}`